# Handling overflow in tables

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-tables

If I have a table like this very very simple example:

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:300px;
}

.td1 {
    width:100px;
}
.td2 {
    width:200px;
}
```

and in one of my `.td2` contains an image that is, lets say, `300px` in `width`. I would like to show scroll bars to allow users to scroll to see it all. However I don't think this is possible, is it?

So my questions are:

1. Are there any other options apart from `hidden` for handling overflow in tables?
2. Is it possible to show scroll-bars only when content pushes beyond a set width? (I swear I've seen it in some forum software but I can't remember which one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
overflow: auto
```

> Content is clipped and scrolling is
>   added only when necessary.

Put the image inside a div in the table cell and make the width and height of the div to be 100% of the td and style it to overflow: auto

```
<style>
.test { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; } 
</style>

<td>
<div class="test">
your image
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: I've tried but to no avail, it just plows on by and spills out into the page!

Comment: Ooh i didn't see you saying about putting the image inside a div... will try that now