# Try to replace table tag by some divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make collection divs like a table so this is my stylesheet file :

```
.maindiv {
display:table;
}
.divheader {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
}
.divfooter {
     width:100%;
    height:20%;
}
.middlediv {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:70%;
}
.divinheader {
    display:table-column;
    width:10%;
    height:80%;
}
.divinfooter {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
.leftofmiddle {
     display:table-column;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
}
.rightofmiddle {
     display:table-column;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
}
.middleofmiddle {
     display:table-column;
    width:60%;
    height:100%;
}
.divinleftofmiddle {
     display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:40%;
}
```

and here is my html tags :

```
 <div class="maindiv">
  <div class="divheader">
        <div class="divinheader"></div> 
        <div class="divinheader"></div>
        <div class="divinheader"></div> 
        <div class="divinheader"></div> 
        <div class="divinheader"></div> 
        <div class="divinheader"></div> 
        <div class="divinheader"></div> 
        <div class="divinheader"></div> 
        <div class="divinheader"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="middlediv">
        <div class="leftofmiddle">
            <div class="divinleftofmiddle"></div>
            <div class="divinleftofmiddle"></div>
        </div>
<div class="middleofmiddle">

</div>
        <div class="rightofmiddle"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="divfooter">
        <div class="divinfooter"></div>
        <div class="divinfooter"></div>
    </div>
        </div>
```

but it doesn't appear like a table ,just each div appears in a new line

> I've checked some answers here but seems they all depending on there are the same number of divs in each row

Comment: Why are you avoiding using <table> ?

Comment: are you displaying table data? Or just converting a layout? Tablet data is well and good in `<table>` don't make it pointlessly difficult by just making more work to have it work as `<div>`s

Comment: as I said "**Try to**" 
I'm trying to have a better control , so I'm using them as containers not just a table data

Comment: actually I used to use `<table>` but I face some problems with styling it

Comment: If the problem is styling, then you will have the exact same problems when you use divs with `display:table` instead of actual tables. Anyway, you've got structural errors: what's with all the table columns inside the rows? What layout are you trying to achieve? Can you provide a screenshot of what you're after?

Comment: I understood the following: your page layout is (or was until very recently) based on a table. You are about to change to a div layout (or did so recently) because you had not enough control over the styling of the table-based page-layout. 
You could use [css-3 display table](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using/) but if you need something that behaves exactly like a table i would recommend to stay with a table-based page layout and to tell us about the styling problems you are having.

Comment: It looks there are many issues here. table-column should be used in side table-column-group. table-cell should be used inside table-row. If there are multiple rows within table, then there should be match between columns, else use table inside table. Its very hard to know what are your requirements. So I would suggest, post the kind of layout you want in table format or some picture format here so that we can help you.

Comment: @three you are right ... well .. I want to fix the width and height of my cells but in percent **%** ... it always extends !

Comment: hence that I'm doling a lot of colspans and cellpadings

Comment: and always scroll bars appears to me :/

Comment: Colspans? You can't simulate those with CSS, period. Stop trying. Anyway, I don't see any scrollbars when I put your source in a jsfiddle, so this is not your real source, is it? Without your real source, we can't help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/Nervf/ here is what I have tried so far. The cell divs should need to have `display:table-cell`. However, since the header has 10 cells, the cells in the next rows are not aligning properly because of `colspan` attribute. I'm not sure how to use this attribute in stylesheet.

Comment: I still do not know which layout you would like to have and which parts should have what relative size (percent of x). 

I created this little [table example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LtCjy). This seems to work. Normal text wraps inside a cell. By extends i assume that your code does not [handle overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471210/)

To be able to help i need more information what you want to achieve and why / how it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use table structure and it is possible to create styling is well, try it.